# MDX sort order in Crossjoin

Tags: mdx, iccube, iccube-reporting, mdx-query

I want to show a list of callers we have missed calls from within a daterange. I want te result to be ordered by date. But I can't figure out how to do this.

My MDX statement:

```
   With   
   Member [Measures].[Gemist] AS
        sum(
            except({[CM resultaat].[Resultaat].[CM resultaat].allmembers},
                {[CM resultaat].[Resultaat].[CM resultaat].[answer],[CM resultaat].[Resultaat].[CM resultaat].[answer overflow]}),
            [Measures].[SN Gesprekken]
        )

Select
   order([Measures].[Gemist],[Datum].[Datum].currentMember.value, ASC) on 0,
    nonempty(crossjoin(Hierarchize([ServiceNummer ANI].[Ani]),[Datum].[Datum].[Dag]),[Measures].[Gemist]) on 1
FROM (SELECT {[datum].[datum].[dag].[2020-04-01]:[datum].[datum].[dag].[2020-04-28]} ON 0 FROM [Cube])
```

After some google searches I tried this to order the measure by date but also tried to order the crossjoin. Output stays te same, no order on date:

[image: Missed calls should be sorted on date]

 
Anyone has a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to order the vertical axis (i.e., the axis 1):

```
order(
  nonempty(
    crossjoin( [ServiceNummer ANI].[Ani], [Datum].[Datum].[Dag] )
  ),
  [Datum].[Datum].currentMember.key,
  BASC

) on 1
```

using the key (or name) of the current member of the [Datum] dimension.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thnx! I'm confused I'm sure I tried this before. But your solutions works as I want it!